# In the deltaX of an Android animation, should I use pixels or percentage?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have, in design view, placed a view right outside of the right boundary of the android device screen. I want to play an animation and move it from outside of the screen into the screen to make an entrance effect, nothing fancy.

However I've been struggling with the deltaX parameters ever since. What is the correct numbers to put down? Shall I go with pixels or percentage?

When I give the correct input, the correct event was fired but the view is nowhere to be found, it doesn't show up on screen at all.

Here is my problematic code:

Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

The view in question:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/android_gridview_menu"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/MainUI"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all translate the grid view out of the screen and then play animation

```
// Translating grid view out of the screen
GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_menu);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point(); 
display.getSize(size);
gridView.setTranslationX(size.x);


// Call this method to bring grid view from right by animation
private void playEnterAnimation(){
    GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_menu);
    gridView.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(200).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really work, I believe using the anime resource file is more reasonable.

Comment: This playEnterAnimation() method will work only when you first translate the view out of the screen by using the code // Translating grid view out of the screen
GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_menu);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point(); 
display.getSize(size);
gridView.setTranslationX(size.x);

Answer (score 0):

To play an animation use `Animation` and `AnimationUtils`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
            R.anim.animation); // R.anim.animation is your animation xml.

    GridView layout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_menu);
    layout.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Hope it help!